# Facebook Graph API: All photos owned by user

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to form a graph request to get all photos owned by a user (posted by that user).
Right now I can get all albums via `/uid/albums` and then query each album via `/aid/photos`, but thats a lot of requests.

I used to be able to do this in fql but now fql is screwy. Is there any way to do this or am I gonna have to iterate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Graph calls you are going to have to iterate. FQL would be the easier (if not faster) option. If there is something fishy with the calls, file a bug.